# Google Password Manager or Dedicated Password Manager

Tags: privacy

Is it better to use Google Password Manager to store all my passwords or a dedicated Password Manager such as Bitwarden? I have been using the former for years and am wondering if I should make the switch now that it is 2019.

Comment: I believe the Google Password Manager only works as part of Chrome, while Bitwarden has plugins for other browsers.

Comment: The main concern I have is, If you're going to use Google Password Manager, then you have to use Google Chrome as your main browser. That's just not good for your privacy. Another thing is Google+ exposed millions of users data and they tried to hide it. Is that sound like a trustworthy company? I don't know.

Comment: This is looking like an opinion-seeking question. Is there something specific you are worried about? You are going to get a lot of opinions on a lot of different facets to the situation (as evidenced by DT's comment about a side issue)

Answer (score 4):

There is no right or wrong answer to this as "better" is a subjective term.
Things you should consider though:

- Google Password Manager is not open source: This means it can not be audited by anyone outside of Google (are they stealing your passwords?... probably not, but who knows).
- Bitwarden is open source: This means that members of the security community can audit it (does this ensure there is no vulnerabilities? no, but you can find them if you like).